# Repeat loop of Jekyll Data

Tags: jekyll

Is it possible to repeat loops of data? Something like so:

```
{% for competition in site.data.competitions loop:3 %}
```

Which would loop and export the the data 3 times?

It would just save me making lots of fake data =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there's a Liquid filter to do it, but you can always put a for in a for:

```
{% for i in (1..3) %}
    {% for competition in site.data.competitions %}
         ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah this does the trick! Thanks!